# Use one "updatable" library in different Android Studio projects

Tags: android, git, android-studio

So the problem is that every library in Android studio must be included as module (copied).

I have HomeApp project at Home, Also i have WorkApp project at Work, i also have a MyLib library that i am using in both projects.

The thing is that i am not able to update library easily.

When at work, i want to be able to change library, update it, add new classes... And to be able to commit changes to git, then i want to get home, just pull all library changes and use newest version of library. And do the same at home: update lib, commit... And then at work just pull and have newest lib.

With Eclipse it was possible because i was able just open existing library and use it. With Android Studio i must import module every time i want to have newest lib version.

I don't want to publish my library changes on maven and then use it as dependency in projects. It is long process that i want to avoid.

Comment: if you don't like maven use local libs folder to place your library in

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? "With Android Studio i must import module every time i want to have newest lib version" -- what are the specific symptoms that you see when just using `git pull` to update an already-imported library?

Comment: pskink - I like maven. But lets assume i want to add new method to class of library. So to be able to use this method on project, i must publish library again to maven. then sync library using grandle in my project to use that method. To much pain. Local libs folder is for jar files as i know. Fix me if i am wrong. I don't want to build jar or aar every time.

Comment: CommonsWare: Imported library is just a copy of real library. So if i pull changes to library. The project will not know about them because he will have his own copy of that library. How can i add cloned library in my project and make changes to library and be able to commit them.